# Concatenar dos columnas manteniendo el formato de las mismas

Tags: excel

Tengo una columna A que se refiere a fechas en el formato personalizado: `"mm/dd/yyyy"` y una columna B que se refiere a las horas en el formato personalizado: `"hh:mm:ss"`. Pues bien, necesito concatenar ambas columnas y crear una columna C pero que mantengan el formato de las anteriores.

Ejemplo:

```
Columna A: 01/25/2022
Columna B: 08:45:00
La columna C debería quedar: 01/25/2022 08:45:00
```

No consigo concatenarlas y que queden con el formato adecuado, ni dándoles luego un formato personalizado del tipo `"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano compañer@s!

Comment: No las concatenes, súmalas y aplica el formato nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Si la columna A tiene formato fecha y la columna B tiene formato hora, puedes usar esta formula: **=TEXTO(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " " & TEXTO(B1, "hh:mm:ss")**

Esta fórmula primero formatea la fecha en la celda A1 como "mm/dd/yyyy" utilizando la función TEXTO(), luego concatena ese resultado con el valor de la celda B1, el cual se formatea como hora en el formato "hh:mm:ss" utilizando nuevamente la función TEXTO(). Ambas partes se unen con un espacio entre ellas.

Answer (score 0):

La fórmula CONCATENAR más simple para combinar los valores de las celdas A2 y B2 es la siguiente:

En el caso de separar texto o en este caso fecha, utilizamos las comillas con el espacio dentro de esta. Ver la formula concatenar siguiente:

= CONCATENAR (A2;”  “;B2)  /devuelve 01/25/2022 08:45:00 como resultado
En el caso de que quiera ver otros ejemplos te dejo este enlace [siempreexcel.com](https://siempreexcel.com/funcion-concatenar-en-excel/)